# How to set default value of vector<vector<string>> in boost program options

Tags: c++, boost

I am getting a compilation error when I set the default of value of `vector<vector<string>>` in Boost program options.

Following  is the line where I set the default value

```
("A", po::value< std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>> &funcCols_)->multitoken()->default_value(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>(), ""), "function_columns")
```

Compilation error:

```
In file included from 
third_party_include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:421:0,
             from 
third_party_include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:13,
             from third_party_include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
```

What is correct way to set the default value in  this case?

Comment: Is this the full compilation error? It doesn't look like it. Is line 15 the line where you set the default value? Please post the full error and additional information so that people know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier, so you can read your own code:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > svvector;
svvector funcCols_;

// ...
po::value<svvector>(&funcCols_)->multitoken()->default_value(svvector(), "")
```